# Call Programs with Python Output

Tags: python, bash, output

I want to call the c program `display_output` with python generated arguments, however I'm not sure how to formulate the syntax.   I tried this

`./display_output (python -c "print 'A' * 20")`

but I get

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `python'
```

I suppose this goes along with my original question and could help me out with that.  The only way I could find to try running python cmd line output as a bash command was by appending `| bash` to the command.  However, is there a better way to do this?

```
(python -c "print 'ls'") | bash
```

I clearly don't know my way around Bash, but I was certain there was a more appropraite way to do this.

Comment: Figured it out.  I added quotes like so:  ./display_output '(python -c "print 'A' * 20")' -_-

Comment: Nevermind, now have weird output.  This doesn't work python -c "print 'A' * 20" | ./display_output

Comment: what is your c code?

Comment: It prints whatever is put into it.

Comment: still think you would find this easier to do using python itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When bash sees an open parenthesis at a place where a command can be, it will launch a subshell to run the enclosed commands. Where you currently have them is not a place where a command can go. What you want instead is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

```bsh
./display_output $(python -c "print 'A' * 20") 
# ...............^
```

You will get into trouble if any of the arguments generated contain whitespace (obviously not the case for this toy example.

To generate a string of 20 "A"s in bash, you would write:

```bsh
a20=$(printf "%20s" "")    # generate a string of 20 spaces   
# or, the less readable but more efficient: printf -v a20 "%20s" ""
a20=${a20// /A}            # replace all spaces with A's
```

The last line is pattern replacement in [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: I get an illegal instruction error with the first example.

Comment: What shell are you using? What do you get with `echo $(python -c "print 'A' * 20") `

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, follow the link and scroll down

Comment: Sorry, the illegal instruction error went away when I changed the amount of generated A's and flipped the double parentheses with singles, and vice versa.